# Plotting geodesic curve in equirectangular images in Cuda

Tags: image-processing

How can I plot geodesic curves in equirectangular images using cuda?

Starting from an image like this:

[image]

I want to plot on it a curve like this:

[image]

Starting from 3D cartesian coordinates, the spherical coordinates are expressed in terms of the longitude and latitude angles because r = 1. 
They are computed as follows:

$$ \text{lat} = \arcsin(z) = \arcsin\left(− \sin(\beta) \cos(\theta)\right)$$

$$\text{long} = \arctan\left(\frac xy\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{\cos(\beta)\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}\right) = \tan \left(\frac{−\cos(\beta)}{\tan(\theta)}\right)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This feels like a programming question more than a signal processing question. Is that feeling right?

Comment: ok, voting to close this as general programming question (which is off-topic here, but would be on-topic on StackOverflow, if you showed what you've coded / tried so far, and what problems you did encounter). Other than that interpretation, one could also say this feels like you're asking for *code written to a specification*, which is also off-topic.